# How to compile two C programs?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

This is my makefile:

```
all: prgrm1 prgrm2

prgrm1: prgrm1.c
     gcc -o prgrm1 prgrm1.c -lrt

prgrm2: prgrm2.c
     gcc -o prgrm2 prgrm2.c -lrt
```

When I try to compile I get the message "Nothing to be done for 'all'."

I made sure that I used tabs not spaces so that is not it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do `prgrm1` and `prgrm2` already exist? If so, `touch` either (or both) of your `c` files.

Comment: Try changing one of the files and running make. Usually that message means they have already been compiled and nothing has changed since they were last compiled. You do not need to change any code simply add a comment and try to recompile

Comment: This was it. I didn't know that. It bugged me for way too long... Thank You!!